# Signals interrupting the message queue primitives and system calls

Tags: linux, qt, operating-system, signals, message-queue

I have a Qt program which contains :

1. Many Qt [signal-slot](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) pairs, for implementing some socket programming.
2. System calls for doing some file operations
3. Some Posix Message queue code, in which, process waits for some message to be written on the queue, reads it and processes.

I am facing two problems :

i. *Sometimes*, while process is waiting on the queue to read some message, the value returned by the function `mq_receive` according to the documentation translates to the message `Interrupted system call`.

ii. *Sometimes*, while process is doing the file operation using the system call, application crashes.

Now I read [here](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Interrupted-Primitives.html) how I can use `TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY` macro for retrying the failed call.

Q1. Can the problem behind my two issues be this same reason as I am using Qt signal/slot mechanism?

Q2. If so, is `TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY` the only good/standard way to handle such situations ? or Qt provides some other way out of it ?

Q3. Are Qt generated signals causing issue with other primitives ? And why it happens only with message queues and system calls and not other C++ primitives ?

Can someone post a link to some article/book where I can understand how and why signals/routines/system calls might cause problems with each other ? I can't make out what exact keywords I shall be googling/binging ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to investigate [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/10138) and [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/4944). Maybe, it makes sense to use QThread instead of POSIX messaging, or as suggested by one of the link [Qt Local sockets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocalsocket.html).
Before all these, it will be good for you to read about event loops in Qt GUI and QThreads.